Entity Framework query filter is not being applied
I am applying a query filter globally on all entities that inherit from EntityBase class:
// filtering not deleted items
Expression<Func<EntityBase, bool>> filterExpr = eb => !eb.IsDeleted;
foreach (var mutableEntityType in modelBuilder.Model.GetEntityTypes())
{
    // check if current entity type is child of BaseModel
    if (mutableEntityType.ClrType.IsAssignableTo(typeof(EntityBase)))
    {
        // modify expression to handle correct child type
        var parameter = Expression.Parameter(mutableEntityType.ClrType);
        var body = ReplacingExpressionVisitor.Replace(filterExpr.Parameters.First(), parameter, filterExpr.Body);
        var lambdaExpression = Expression.Lambda(body, parameter);

        // set filter
        mutableEntityType.SetQueryFilter(lambdaExpression);
    }
}

But when I try to use it here:
var category = await categoryRepository.GetByIdAsync(id);

I still get the soft deleted entities.
Here is the categoryRepository.GetByIdAsync code:
public async Task<T?> GetByIdAsync(Guid id, 
    bool noTracking = false,
    params Expression<Func<T, object>>[] includeProperties)
{
    IQueryable<T> query = dbSet;

    if (noTracking) 
    {
        query = query.AsNoTracking();
    }

    if (includeProperties != null)
    {
        foreach (var includeProperty in includeProperties)
        {
            query = query.Include(includeProperty);
        }
    }

    return await query.FirstOrDefaultAsync(e =>
        EF.Property<Guid>(e, "Id") == id);
}


This is because the global query filter you applied with SetQueryFilter is being ignored when calling categoryRepository.GetByIdAsync(id). The query filter you set on EntityBase works automatically with LINQ queries that are generated by EF Core, but it doesn't affect the code you have in GetByIdAsync, where you're manually filtering the entities with EF.Property<Guid>(e, "Id") == id. The global query filter (!eb.IsDeleted) works on queries generated by EF Core, but because you're using a custom FirstOrDefaultAsync with EF.Property<Guid>, it bypasses the global filter.

@SarthakBhan i did added an explicit condition in the GetByIdAsync function it worked.

@SarthakBhanin another function i am doing this
 public async Task<ServiceResult<IEnumerable<CategoryResponseDto>>> GetAll(SieveModel? sieveModel) {     var categoriesQuery = categoryRepository.GetAsQueryable();     categoriesQuery = sieveProcessor.Apply(sieveModel, categoriesQuery);     var categories = await categoriesQuery.ToListAsync();     return ServiceResult<IEnumerable<CategoryResponseDto>>         .Ok("Categories retrieved successfully", mapper.Map<IEnumerable<CategoryResponseDto>>(categories)); }

@SarthakBhan
does that cause the same issue cause it is not working here too maybe because  ofsieve? or because of using query

Try my extension ApplyQueryFilter which simplifies things and combines existing filters if any. For the first sight I do not see reason why your filter is not working,

@MarkoSami Yes, The issue arises because the global query filter (!eb.IsDeleted) is being bypassed when you apply the SieveProcessor in your GetAll method. The SieveProcessor.Apply likely modifies the query, causing the global filter to be ignored.
After applying the SieveProcessor, manually add the global filter for IsDeleted
categoriesQuery = categoriesQuery.Where(c => !c.IsDeleted);
This will make sure global filter is always applied

Just to eliminate the obvious, you checked that Category and any related ones you are including extends EntityBase and that the code to apply the query filter is executing correctly for that entity? Also, is the issue that you are getting a category back by ID even though it is soft-deleted, or included entities that were soft-deleted?

Please [edit] your question if you have more relevant details. Don't post code in comments. And if you do, make sure it's clear what the code does. I.e. turn the question into a [mre].

This is because the global query filter you applied with SetQueryFilter is being ignored when calling categoryRepository.GetByIdAsync(id). The query filter you set on EntityBase works automatically with LINQ queries that are generated by EF Core, but it doesn't affect the code you have in GetByIdAsync, where you're manually filtering the entities with EF.Property<Guid>(e, "Id") == id. The global query filter (!eb.IsDeleted) works on queries generated by EF Core, but because you're using a custom FirstOrDefaultAsync with EF.Property<Guid>, it bypasses the global filter.

Negative. Global query filters are added to any IQueryable query produced from some EF Core model root (DbSet). If one has to explicitly add them to queries, they (global query filters) would have been totally unusable. The OP issue must be caused by something else not shown in the post.

@IvanStoev What else can be the problem?

Many things. For instance, the global query filter setting code not being executed. Or the entity in question being somehow missed/exclude by that code. Or some code removing the filter afterwards (SetQueryFilter is not additive, the last wins). Or some hidden code/interceptor calling IgnoreQueryFilters etc. OP needs to provide [mre] so the people could reproduce, debug if needed and identify the cause. By general EF Core principles (and that's wrong in your answer) the OP code should work,

I rolled back your revision. A question asked in a comment is very annoying. OP shouldn't do that and it shouldn't be answered. The code is hard to read in the first place and we have no idea what it does and how it is related to the question itself.

Also, the answer is based on mere guesswork (it clearly isn't tested).
